# Can I use the CastCompanionLibrary if I don't use an ActionBar

Tags: android, chromecast

I currently am in the process of migrating my Chromecast app to the new sdk. I am trying to use the CastCompanionLibrary to make my life easier, but I am running into a problem.  I don't currently use an actionBar in my app and I plan to add it later on when I redesign the app so for now I can't use an ActionBar.   Can I use the CastCompanionLibrary even if I don't use an ActionBar?

Thanks!!

Comment: The answer I found is no you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it only supports ActionBar, at least for discovery part. What implementation of discovery are you having in mind?

Comment: I was just using it for everything else but discovery.. Is it possible for me to handle the discovery/hiding of the mediaRouterButton but use the CastCmpanionLibrary for everything else?   So basically i wouldn't call this line of code:


      mVideoCastManager.addMediaRouterButton(menu, 
    R.id.media_route_menu_item);

and would handle the discovery on my own.

Comment: Looks like you have already tried that; are you running into any issues?

Comment: hehe i didn't try that. i'll give this a go, it's well written good job Ali!  I'll come back when i try it and get to that stage.

Comment: It is on my todo list to add MediaRouterButton support; currently it is just for Action Provider. Please do report your findings.

Comment: CCL now supports MediaRouterButton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton` instead `android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider` on Actionbar.